# Can I update the same file and do a pullrequest again?

Tags: git

I submitted a pull request and this is not approved yet. Is it possible to update/commit the same file and do a pull request again? If yes how can I see the changes / which files are committed?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do another pull request?  Depending on the platform, the PR should update if you make new commits to the existing one.

Comment: Which project hosting service are you using? GitHub? Stash? GitLab?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have changed a file **F.txt** and created a pull request from **Branch A** to **Branch B**.

**Branch A** can be from any repository and **Branch B** can be from any repository it really doesn't matter. Once you have raised a pull request and it hasn't been approved you can keep making changes to **Branch A** and the new commits that you have added in **Branch A** will automatically be added to the pull request that you have raised.

So, **there is no need to create a new pull request** for the new changes. And you can make the changes to any file in branch and not just limited to the change made to file **F.txt**.

Use [this](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) link to know more about pullrequests for GitHub

Use [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+pull+requests+in+Stash) link to know more about pull request model followed in Stash

**In both the models, you can simply update the files in the branches and the pull request will be updated accordingly**

> Pull requests can be sent from any branch or commit but it's
>   recommended that a topic branch be used so that follow-up commits can
>   be pushed to update the pull request if necessary.